# How to prefetch stored value in dropdown in innerhtml and submit as it is if option is not changed?

Tags: javascript, php, innerhtml

I have an inline editable table that has dropdowns and able to fetch the stored value from the database but unable to store the data unless the option value is clicked once again and chosen if I don't choose any option, all the values from that dropdown is been stored.

```js
function edit_row(id) {

  var machine = '<?php
  require_once("dbcontrollernew.php");
  $db_handle1 = new DBController();
  $querydept = "SELECT * FROM production ";
  $machine = $db_handle1 - > runQuery($querydept);
  foreach($machine as $machine) { ? >
      <
      option value = "<?php echo htmlentities($machine['machine_name']);?>" > <?php echo htmlentities($machine['machine_name']);?> < /option><?php
    } ? > <?php
      require_once("dbcontrollernew.php");
      $db_handle1 = new DBController();
      $querydept ="SELECT * FROM machine where status='1'";
      $machine = $db_handle1->runQuery($querydept);
      foreach($machine as $machine)
        { ?> <
    option value = "<?php echo htmlentities($machine['machinecode']);?>" > <?php echo htmlentities($machine['machinecode']);?> < /option><?php
} ? > ';


document.getElementById("machine_name1" + id).innerHTML = "<select class='form-control' style='width:100px' id='machine_text" + id + "'><option value='" + machine + "'" + machine + "></option></select>";
}
```

Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `document.querySelector(selector)` get dropdown and then loop over it to get `values` of each option.

For better understanding, I have added a jsfiddle link below:
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/f9q76jz2/1/)

```
const dropdown = document.querySelector('select');
// for display text of dropdown
document.querySelector('#text').innerHTML = dropdown.innerText;
let values = ""

// for values of dropdown
for(let options of dropdown){
    values += options.value;
}
document.querySelector('#value').innerHTML = values;
```